# Azure Devops + postman automate export of collection

Tags: azure-devops, postman

Hi I have a devops pipeline that happily run postman tests (yml) however the process is not ideal.
I am using the NewmanPostman task

Whenever a collection is modified I have to

1. Manually export collection
2. Save it to a Repo
3. Run the pipeline

I know that given a postman Api key I could totally avoid the above steps but I cannot figure out how.
What I hoping that I could download the collection in the pipeline and use that in my NewmanPostam task.

My current task uses

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman

```
- task: NewmanPostman@4
  displayName: 'Postman tests'
  inputs:
    collectionSourceType: 'file'
    collectionFileSource: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: 'src/Postman/Collections/xyzCollection.postman_collection.json'
    environment: 'src/Postman/Environments/dev.postman_environment.json'
    ignoreRedirect: false
    reporters: junit
    reporterJUnitExport: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Results/JunitResults.xml'
    bail: false    
    sslInsecure: false
    htmlExtraDarkTheme: false
    htmlExtraLogs: false
    htmlExtraTestPaging: false
  continueOnError: true
```

as someone done this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you have referenced the static Collection file, you should be able to replace that with the Postman API URL for that collection. The API Key can be then added as a param on the URL.

```
newman run "https://api.getpostman.com/collections/UID?apikey=APIKey"
```

More info about running Newman with a Collection URL can be found here:

https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman#using-newman-with-the-postman-api

The Postman API reference collection can be found in this public workspace:

https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-public-workspace/collection/12959542-c8142d51-e97c-46b6-bd77-52bb66712c9a?ctx=documentation

---

**EDIT**

From the list of options in the source file, it's looks like this is the way to use a URL as the collection file.

```yaml
- task: NewmanPostman@4
  displayName: 'Postman tests'
  inputs:
    collectionSourceType: 'url'
    collectionURL: 'https://api.getpostman.com/collections/<UID>?apikey=APIKey'
    environmentSourceType: 'url'
    environmentUrl: 'https://api.getpostman.com/environments/<UID>?apikey=APIKey'
    ignoreRedirect: false
    reporters: junit
    reporterJUnitExport: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Results/JunitResults.xml'
    bail: false    
    sslInsecure: false
    htmlExtraDarkTheme: false
    htmlExtraLogs: false
    htmlExtraTestPaging: false
  continueOnError: true
```

Getting the `UID` of the Collection or Environment in the V8 app is as simple as copying it from the `info` section, on the right side context menu.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply , I have edited my question which includes the newman task I am using , are you saying  I can replace "contents" which is where I keep my static path with the postman URL?

Comment: I'm not sure how they have mapped those names to the internal Newman commands - You should be able to have `collection: <Postman API collection URL>` or `environment: <Postman API environment URL>`

Comment: Ok I will have a fiddle with what you are suggesting, otherwise I have to revert to a script based approch and google about that one too as the task that I am using made life way easier...

Comment: It's using Newman under the hood and sending that file data to that lib. Newman takes a static JSON file or a URL (Postman API or something that returns the Collection JSON format). There shouldn't be a reason why that wouldn't work unless the Task is specifically blocking that from happening.

Comment: thanks for your help , really appreciate it , may be I am missing the obvious still "newish" to postman + devops but given the apikey what is the syntax to refer to a particular collection to test. how do you append it? do you see what I mean? so if I have a "xyzcollection" to test how that fit in int the url

Comment: For a collection - The URL would be `'https://api.getpostman.com/collections/<Your Collection UID>?apikey=12345ABC'`. I've updated the answer to include where that UID can be found. You can also make a call in Postman use `https://api.getpostman.com/collections?apikey=12345ABC` to get all the collections.

Comment: extremely grateful! about to test now.. found the collectionId as you said.

Comment: Keep getting no collection found but I checked a million times and the Id and postman key are correct. but anyway your help has been invaluble. any suggestions

Comment: Are you getting that error from the Task or sending the raw request (`https://api.getpostman.com/collections/<Your Collection UID>?apikey=12345ABC`) to get the collection data? If the request works and returns the data, then it's a problem with the Task. The example I added is just that, an example...I don't know if that task has something called `collection` or it's called something else :D

Comment: Checked the source code on GH to check the values (https://github.com/carlowahlstedt/NewmanPostman_VSTS_Task/blob/master/NewmanPostman/task.json) and updated the example task in the answer

Comment: I am going to use a script like newman run etc.. and see if makes a difference looks like no supported https://github.com/carlowahlstedt/NewmanPostman_VSTS_Task/issues/46

Comment: Did you try the updated yml I added to the answer?

Comment: yes I get "#[error]Provided string "http://" for collection is not a valid url" weird . obviously my string is a full url